# Curl command doesn't work in config file on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-cron

I have a Django web application that is deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk (Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.3). I am trying to run the following config file

```
files:
    "/usr/local/bin/cron_tab.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            exec &>> /tmp/cron_tab_log.txt
            date > /tmp/date
            source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
            cd /var/app/current
            python manage.py crontab add
            exit 0

container_commands:
    cron_tab:
        command: "curl /usr/local/bin/cron_tab.sh | bash"
```

This file placed in the .ebextentions folder. All other config files are working properly. However, this one is not working. Also, I have tried to run the `container_commands` code manually on SSH and it gives output such as below.

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

I also checked the `/tmp` folder but there is no ***cron_tab_log.txt***. I checked `/usr/local/bin` the ***cron_tab.sh*** is located there.

I just want this Django-crontab run after the deploy and it doesn't work. How can I handle this issue?

Comment: `curl` is a utility used for making web requests. Why are you using it here? Did you mean to do `bash /usr/local/bin/cron_tab.sh` instead of `curl /usr/local/bin/cron_tab.sh | bash`?

Answer (score 1):

Curl is used for web url call not executing a script, I think you need to change the last line in your config file to be:

`command: "sudo /usr/local/bin/cron_tab.sh"`